# Perl: syntax error ")[". array slicing

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

I'm new to Perl and was experimenting around a bit. I have this code:

```
use Digest::MD5 'md5';
use Data::Dumper::Perltidy;

my $data = "x";
my $digest = md5($data);

# print first 6 elements
print Dumper map(ord, split(//, $digest))[0..5];
```

But that fails with a syntax error. I remember that PHP had similar problems whereby they planned to fix this in future releases. Does Perl still have this issue or is it just the wrong way to do this? How would be the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to apply a subscript to the map function, not it's values.

```
print Dumper +( map(ord, split(//, $a) ))[0 .. 5];
```

Will do what you expect. Note the use of the `+` sign in order to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 10):

You need to enclose `map` in parens for slicing to work, e.g.:

```
print Dumper( ( map ord, split(//, $digest) )[0..5] );
```

Comment: That still fails with a syntax error? Are you sure? When was this introduced?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I also missed the parens for the `Dumper` function.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other working answers consider that you are limiting the result of the `map` statement, when you could get the same results by limiting the split. This will pass less data to be mapped by `ord` and save your program some work:

```
print Dumper map(ord, ( split(//, $digest) )[0..5] );
```

But since split has this built in it can be simplified further to

```
print Dumper map(ord, split(//, $digest, 6) );
```

Comment: Just to make this absolutely clear: `map` in Perl is not lazy? Are there any lazy functions?

Comment: In Perl 5 the expression or block executed by `map` for each input value may contain side effects. To ensure that any side effects remain as deterministic as possible `map` executes in order, serially across all input values. Perl has very little hope of being able to identify when a `map` will have no side effects and convert it to a lazy `map`, consider that Perl allow overriding `&CORE::GLOBAL::ord` which could result in the calls to `ord` having a side effect.